# Modifying a class to display specific output

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and am having a bit of trouble with this bit in particular. Attached is some code I need to run as part of a project. Details are at the end.

```
 class Screen:DataSource {
    var items:[String]=[]
    func run(){
        let lv = TableView()
        items = ["John","Paul","George","Ringo"]
        let ds = self
        lv.dataSource=ds
        lv.drawList()
    }
}

class TableView {
    // This class displays a list given a DataSource
    var dataSource:DataSource?
    init (){
        self.dataSource=nil
    }

    func drawList(){
        for(var i=0;i<dataSource!.getSize();i++) {
            print("\(dataSource!.getItem(at:i))")
            print("--------------------------")
        }
    }
}

protocol DataSource {
    func getSize()->Int
    func getItem(at pos:Int)->String
}

let screen = Screen()
screen.run()
```

Without changing the "run" function/method, I need to have it print this:

```
John
--------------------------
Paul
--------------------------
George
--------------------------
Ringo
--------------------------
```

I'm not sure what to modify in my Screen class. This is what I have so far:

```
class Screen: DataSource {    
     var items: [String]=[]    
     func run() {        
          let lv = TableView()        
          items = ["John","Paul","George","Ringo"]        
          let ds = self        
          lv.dataSource=ds        
          lv.drawList()    
     }
     //NEED HELP HERE
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to write the code for `getSize()` and `getItem()` in your `Screen` class.

Comment: "I need to have it print this" What does it print now?

Comment: Thank you! How do I write the code for getSize() and getItem() inside of a class? (New to Swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an extension to make `Screen` conform to `DataSource`:

```
 class Screen {
    var items:[String]=[]
    func run(){
        let lv = TableView()
        items = ["John","Paul","George","Ringo"]
        let ds = self
        lv.dataSource=ds
        lv.drawList()
    }
}

extension Screen: DataSource {
    func getSize() -> Int { return items.count }
    func getItem(at index:Int) -> String { return items[index] }
}
```

You could also put the `DataSource` conformance and methods on the class itself, but doing it in an extension is a common style for organizing your class's members.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the portion of code I'm writing must go inside the Screen class itself. Is there a way to include your answer in my class without the extension?

Comment: As I said, you can just put the methods in the class itself.